# CSS3:transition does't work when the background color is gradient

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have prepared two style of `body`, all of their background is gradient, also I add transition effect to the tag:

```
body{
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 500, from(rgb(240, 240, 240)), to(rgb(190, 190, 190)));
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear 0s;
}

body.orange{
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(35, 35, 35, 1) 60%);
}
```

I use button to toggle between the two style.The problem is the style toggle have no transition effect.

But when I set the background color to pure color,like "red" or "black", the transition effect show again.

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/MTLAJ/3/)

Why this happened?How can I make gradient background color toggle also have transition effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS Transitions specification says that [the color of a background can animate](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css) but gradient is classified as [image](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#gradients).

If you want to get a gradient transition effect you will have to fake it, for example, by placing two elements on top of each other and animating the opacity of the one on top from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0.